# Using livereload with Ngrok and Rails

Tags: reactjs, ngrok

I am using ngrok on a ruby on rails + react project, just today when creating a tunnel, if i access the url the react components won't load, and I can see this warning message:

> [blocked] The page at https://54gc-46-199-197-161.eu.ngrok.io/ was not
> allowed to run insecure content from
> ws://54gc-46-199-197-161.eu.ngrok.io:35729/livereload.
> script.js:1:87195

Comment: Do you need to use `wss`?

Comment: I am not familiar with this or how to use it. And why it wasn't failing until now?

Comment: `http://` and `ws://` are compatible. `https://` requires `wss://` so if you were on a local test copy with no HTTPS you probably didn't have the issue.

Comment: if I copy the link without `https://` it keeps happening. And if i replaced it with `wss://` it fails to load

Comment: This is a security issue in the browser. If the page is secure, all content must be secure as well, and this includes WebSocket (`wss`). Can you explain "fails to load" in more technical terms? Look more closely at your Network inspector, check for other errors in the Console.

Comment: the part of the site that is coded with react does not render, is just blank. Then the footer which is server rendered it shows, but not the part using webpacker